# ellipsize on textview doesnt work

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, ellipsis

I want to display ellipsis if my textview length is too long. But for some reason, it doesnt seem to work. Please take a look at the image on how it looks like:

[image]

Here is my layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
          android:id="@+id/txt1_trans"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textIsSelectable="true"
          android:bufferType="spannable"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:freezesText="true"
          android:focusable="true" 
          android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
          android:text="My Personal > Bank of America savings"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textSize="18sp"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          android:textColor="#000000"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="100$"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt1_trans"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txt1_trans"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the textView on the left (txt1_trans) to display ellipsis if it takes up the space that textview on the right ("TextView2") occupies. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with the layout. For the 2nd TextView on my layout, I have set

> alignParentRight = true

And the 1st TextView has

> width = "wrap_content"

Because of this, both these TextViews end up taking up common space. In order to avoid that, I set the first TextView to_LeftOf 2nd TextView . This ensures that they dont try to write on the same common space . Here is my correct layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
      android:id="@+id/txt1_trans"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textIsSelectable="true"
      android:bufferType="spannable"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView2"
      android:freezesText="true"
      android:focusable="true" 
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:text="My Personal Bank of America savings"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:textColor="#000000"/>

   <TextView 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:id="@+id/TextView2"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:text="100$"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt1_trans"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txt1_trans"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ellipsize with wrap_content as the width. You need to use either wrap_parent or preferably match_parent depending on what version of Android you're targeting.

Comment: no such attribute as `wrap_parent` - you mean `match_parent` or `fill_parent`

Comment: yea my apologies fill_parent