# Android TextView ellipsize can't be used with textIsSelectable?

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView in my Android app. Setting android:textIsSelectable to true works, except when android:ellipsize is also turned on (say, to "END"). In which case, the ellipsize stops working, i.e. the ellipsis no longer appears.

Any ideas on how I can have both set together? i.e. can copy text, and for longer text an ellipsis should appear.

Thanks.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790188/ellipsize-on-textview-doesnt-work

Comment: Sorry, how does that link answer the question?

Comment: having the same problem